# Filter result on the value of a child - xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm getting problems trying to get a data from a xml, I got this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<base>
<!-- OFFERS -->
  <offers>
    <offer status="1">Sale</offer>
    <offer status="2">Rent</offer>
  </offers>

<!--CATEGORIES-->
  <categories>
    <category cat="A">Category 1</category>
    <category cat="B">Category 2</category>
    <category cat="C">Category 3</category>
  </categories>

<!--OBJECTS-->
  <objects>
    <object id="1" offer="1">
      <name>Object 1</name>
      <category cat="A"/>
      <price>12</price>
    </object>

    <object id="2" offer="2">
      <name>Object 1</name>
      <category cat="B"/>
      <price>1000</price>
    </object>

    <object id="3" offer="2">
      <name>Object 1</name>
      <category cat="A"/>
      <price>10</price>
    </object>
  </objects>

    <object id="4" offer="1">
      <name>Object 1</name>
      <category cat="C"/>
      <price>60</price>
    </object>

    <object id="5" offer="2">
      <name>Object 1</name>
      <category cat="A"/>
      <price>30</price>
    </object>
</base>
```

For each category, I need to know the arithmetic mean of the price that is on rent (//offers/offer)

My xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
      <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>AM</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//categories/category">
          <xsl:variable name="cat" select="@cat"/>
          <xsl:variable name="object" select="//object[category/@cat=$cat]"/>
          <xsl:variable name="qtobj" select="count($obj)"/>

          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$object/price div $qtobj"/></td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My main problem is that I don't know how to filter only objects for rent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:key name="obj" match="object" use="concat(category/@cat, '|', @offer)" />

<xsl:template match="/base">
    <xsl:variable name="rent-status" select="offers/offer[.='Rent']/@status" />
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Average Price (Rent Only)</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="categories/category">
                    <xsl:variable name="objects" select="key('obj', concat(@cat, '|', $rent-status))" />
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="sum($objects/price) div count ($objects)"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Going at it your way, you could define:

```
<xsl:variable name="objects" select="//object[category/@cat=current()/@cat and @offer=$rent-status]"/>
```

but using a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) is both more efficient and more elegant.

Comment: Well, I was forgetting other things too. Using keys is still difficult for me, I need to learn a little more and keep practicing, thank you